# BeautifulSoup and php/html files

Tags: php, python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I've been using BeautifulSoup to convert relative URLs in some ancient HTML files from an archival site to absolute URLs (mostly so they can be targeted better by .htaccess rules). This part I've got down: search for certain tags and their atts, use urllib.parse.urljoin (this is Python3) to correct. Fine.

However, there are also some .php files in this collection, from later years of this website. They mostly use 3-5 lines to include other .php files, then the rest is HTML, though there are some exceptions.

**Problem:** BeautifulSoup parsers try to interpret what's between `<?php ?>` tags. In fact, there appear to be cases where they just throw out just the angle brackets, but leave the question marks -- behaviour which I hackishly addressed thus:

```
for c in soup.contents:
    c = str(c) # previously a BeautifulSoup Tag

    # I don't need soup after this point, hence not reconstructing contents
    c = ('<' if c.startswith('?') else '') + c
    c = c + ('>' if c.endswith('?') else '')
```

But in any case, I noticed that whole `<?php ?>` tags were often mangled, in different ways depending on the parser. For example, the html5lib parser takes these lines:

```
<?
//echo "BEGIN PAGE: " . $_SESSION["i"]."<br>";
include ('util.php');
```

And interprets the tag as ending at the `>` that closes `<br>`.

What I'd prefer to happen is for the php tags to be left alone. (Obviously, in an ideal world a parser would read through them and work on any inner HTML, but that seems like asking for too much!)

**Possible solutions**

1. Skip .php files and only work with .html -- the work being done is not essential, just an optimization, so no great loss will ensue;
2. Find a BeautifulSoup parser not mentioned in the docs that handles these cases better;
3. Pre-parse the text myself, extract all `<?php ?>` blocks, and reinsert after the work with BeautifulSoup is done, taking care to recall where they should fall (potentially very difficult if any of these thousands of files have `<?php echo 'foobar' ?>` in the middle of HTML lines, for example)
4. Similarly to the above, programmatically protect all `<?php ?>` tags from the parser, e.g. inserting HTML comments around them, and then remove the protection after the soup

Comment: If you have an answer to your own question, you can add it as an answer rather than including it in the question.

Comment: why would you ask it if you know the answer already?

Comment: It might seem weird if you're not used to this format, but it's the preferred way to do it. [See the help center for more details.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Don't Panic Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question... :)

I used solution #4: programmatically protect all `<?php ?>` tags from the parser by inserting HTML comments around them. The parser then skips interpreting whatever's inside a comment. Later, when using `soup.prettify()` or `soup.contents`, the output can just be given a straightforward replace `<!--<?` with `<?` and likewise for closing tags.

Note that this doesn't work for PHP tags used to generate dynamic content inside certain HTML tags, e.g.:

```
<a href= "<? echo foo_bar(); ?>" >
```

The current versions of `html.parser`, `lxml`, and `html5lib` all interpret this as a series of nonsense attributes of `<a>`, even when the PHP tags are enclosed in HTML comments. In such cases I manually extracted the tags with regex to solve my issue instead.

Comment: As the PHP can sometime be inside quotes, a better solution would be to replace each block with a simple text placeholder which can then be put back afterwards, have a look at: [Get BeautifulSoup to correctly parse php tags or ignore them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55866953/4985733)