# Get BeautifulSoup to correctly parse php tags or ignore them

Tags: php, python, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I currently need to parse a lot of .phtml files, get specific html tags and add a custom data attribute to them.
I'm using python beautifulsoup to parse the entire document and add the tags, and this part works just fine.

The problem is that on the view files (phtml) there are  tags that get parsed too. Below is an example of input-output

INPUT

```
<?php

$stars = $this->getData('sideBarCoStars', []);

if (!$stars) return;

$sideBarCoStarsCount = $this->getData('sideBarCoStarsCount');
$title = $this->getData('sideBarCoStarsTitle');
$viewAllUrl = $this->getData('sideBarCoStarsViewAllUrl');
$isDomain = $this->getData('isDomain');
$lazy_load = $lazy_load ?? 0;
$imageSrc = $this->getData('emptyImageData');
?>
<header>
    <h3>
        <a href="<?php echo $viewAllUrl; ?>" class="noContentLink white">
        <?php echo "{$title} ({$sideBarCoStarsCount})"; ?>
        </a>
    </h3>
```

OUTPUT

```
<?php
$stars = $this->
getData('sideBarCoStars', []);

if (!$stars) return;

$sideBarCoStarsCount = $this-&gt;getData('sideBarCoStarsCount');
$title = $this-&gt;getData('sideBarCoStarsTitle');
$viewAllUrl = $this-&gt;getData('sideBarCoStarsViewAllUrl');
$isDomain = $this-&gt;getData('isDomain');
$lazy_load = $lazy_load ?? 0;
$imageSrc = $this-&gt;getData('emptyImageData');
?&gt;
<header>
 <h3>
  <a class="noContentLink white" href="&lt;?php echo $viewAllUrl; ?&gt;">
   <?php echo "{$title} ({$sideBarCoStarsCount})"; ?>
  </a>
 </h3>
```

I tried different ways, but didn't succeed on making beautifulsoup to ignore the PHP tags. 
Is it possible to get html.parser custom rules to ignore , or to beautifulsoup?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to remove all of the PHP elements before giving it to BeautifulSoup to parse. This can be done using a regular expression to spot all PHP sections and replace them with safe placeholder text.

After carrying out all of your modifications using BeautifulSoup, the PHP expressions can then be replaced.

As the PHP can be anywhere, i.e. also within a quoted string, it is best to use a simple unique string placeholder rather than trying to wrap it in an HTML comment (see `php_sig`).

`re.sub()` can be given a function. Each time the a substitution is made, the original PHP code is stored in an array (`php_elements`). Then the reverse is done afterwards, i.e. search for all instances of `php_sig` and replace them with the next element from `php_elements`. If all goes well, `php_elements` should be empty at the end, if it is not then your modifications have resulted in a place holder being removed.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """<html>
<body>

<?php 
$stars = $this->getData('sideBarCoStars', []);

if (!$stars) return;

$sideBarCoStarsCount = $this->getData('sideBarCoStarsCount');
$title = $this->getData('sideBarCoStarsTitle');
$viewAllUrl = $this->getData('sideBarCoStarsViewAllUrl');
$isDomain = $this->getData('isDomain');
$lazy_load = $lazy_load ?? 0;
$imageSrc = $this->getData('emptyImageData');
?>

<header>
    <h3>
        <a href="<?php echo $viewAllUrl; ?>" class="noContentLink white">
        <?php echo "{$title} ({$sideBarCoStarsCount})"; ?>
        </a>
    </h3>

</body>"""

php_sig = '!!!PHP!!!'
php_elements = []

def php_remove(m):
    php_elements.append(m.group())
    return php_sig

def php_add(m):
    return php_elements.pop(0)

# Pre-parse HTML to remove all PHP elements
html = re.sub(r'<\?php.*?\?>', php_remove, html, flags=re.S+re.M)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Make modifications to the soup
# Do not remove any elements containing PHP elements

# Post-parse HTML to replace the PHP elements
html = re.sub(php_sig, php_add, soup.prettify())

print(html)
```